# parsing txt files in vcfs format

Tags: python, pandas, vcf-variant-call-format

I want to extract information from the txt file to dataframe with the following field in the data

```
1) GENEINFO
2) ID
3) POS
4) ALT
5) CLNSIG
6) CLNDN
```

[The txt file is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zps0YssoJbZHrn6iLte2RDLlgruhAX1s/view?usp=sharing)

I wrote the following code trying to get information from the file, but don't know how to proceed. Could you help me guide through some ideas to do that?

```
import io
import os
import pandas as pd


def read_vcf(path):
    with open('clinvar_final.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = [l for l in f if not l.startswith('##')]
    return pd.read_csv(
        io.StringIO(''.join(lines)),
        dtype={'#CHROM': str, 'POS': int, 'ID': str, 'REF': str, 'ALT': str,
               'QUAL': str, 'FILTER': str, 'INFO': str},
        sep='\t'
    ).rename(columns={'#CHROM': 'CHROM'})
```

Comment: you have to run it  `read_vcf("")`. I don't know why you have `path` in `def read_vcf(path):` if you don't use `path` in code.

Comment: probably you cold do the same with `read_csv('clinvar_final.txt', comment="#", ...)` - doc: [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read it with

```
df = pd.read_csv('clinvar_final.txt', comment='#', sep='\t')
```

and after that you will have tabel already with columns 2) `ID` 3) `POS` 4) `ALT`

```
print(df[['ID', 'POS', 'ALT']].head())
```

gives

```
       ID      POS ALT
0  475283  1014O42   A
1  542074  1O14122   T
2  183381  1014143   T
3  542075  1014179   T
4  475278  1014217   T
```

Other information ( 1) `GENEINFO` 5) `CLNSIG` 6) `CLNDN`) are in column `INFO` as one string and you can extra them to separated columns using `regex`

```
df['GENEINFO'] = df['INFO'].str.extract('GENEINFO=([^;]*)')
df['CLNSIG'] = df['INFO'].str.extract('CLNSIG=([^;]*)')
df['CLNDN'] = df['INFO'].str.extract('CLNDN=([^;]*)')

print(df['GENEINFO'].head())
print(df['CLNSIG'].head())
print(df['CLNDN'].head())
```

Result

```
0    ISG15:9636
1    ISG15:9636
2    ISG15:9636
3    ISG15:9636
4    ISG15:9636
Name: GENEINFO, dtype: object

0                    Benign
1    Uncertain_significance
2                Pathogenic
3    Uncertain_significance
4                    Benign
Name: CLNSIG, dtype: object

0    Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcifi...
1    Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcifi...
2    Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcifi...
3    Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcifi...
4    Immunodeficiency_38_with_basal_ganglia_calcifi...
Name: CLNDN, dtype: object
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('clinvar_final.txt', comment='#', sep='\t')

print(df.columns)

print(df[['ID', 'POS', 'ALT']].head())

df['GENEINFO'] = df['INFO'].str.extract('GENEINFO=([^;]*)')
df['CLNSIG'] = df['INFO'].str.extract('CLNSIG=([^;]*)')
df['CLNDN'] = df['INFO'].str.extract('CLNDN=([^;]*)')

print(df['GENEINFO'].head())
print(df['CLNSIG'].head())
print(df['CLNDN'].head())
```